# not enter in directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i create this directive for validation permission of user for show menu-item or hidden menu

this is my code  :

```
 @Directive({
    selector: '[Permission]'
    })
    export class Pemsittiondirective {

    @Input() AccessName: string;

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private permission: PermissionValidate
    ) {
        console.log(this.AccessName)
        this.show();
     }

    show(): void {
        console.log('in d')
        if (this.permission.validateAccessLevel(this.AccessName)) {

            this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

        } else {

            this.viewContainerRef.clear();

        }

    }

}
```

and i use this directive in HTML :

```
                    <li [Permission]='User:Main' class="side-menu-items-item">
                    <div class="item-icon">
                        <i nz-icon nzType="team" nzTheme="outline"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-label">
                        <label>{{'DASHBOARD.MENU_ITEM.USER_MANAGER' | translate}}</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

`[Permission]='User:Main'`

and i declarations in shared.module :

```
 declarations: [ShowErrorComponent,Pemsittiondirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,

    ZorroModule,
  ],
  exports: [MaterialModule,Pemsittiondirective]
})
```

But it did not work and it did not enter into the `Directive`

**What's the problem? how can I solve it???**
**Update Question :**

this is my `shared.module`

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [ShowErrorComponent,Pemsittiondirective,EmailExistValidationDirective,UsernameValidationDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,

    ZorroModule,
  ],
  exports: [MaterialModule,Pemsittiondirective,ZorroModule ,ShowErrorComponent,EmailExistValidationDirective,UsernameValidationDirective]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    // Forcing the whole app to use the returned providers from the AppModule only.
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ShowErrorComponent ,Pemsittiondirective , EmailExistValidationDirective ,UsernameValidationDirective/* All of your services here. It will hold the services needed by `itself`. */]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: can you create a demo to reproduce the issue on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: can you try: `Permission='User:Main'` instead of `[Permission]='User:Main'`? In the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#apply-the-attribute-directive) they do it that way

Comment: @Keff its not work

Comment: The `[]` just tells angular its an attribute selector, no need to use when applying it to an element, it is also a good practice, angular says, to prefix directives, for example `appPermission`

Comment: not sure what the `User:Main` syntax is. but afaik when using structural directives you need to use the star. `<li *Permission='true'> ` on the element

Comment: Hmm okay, does it give any error? Does it enter in the constructor?

Comment: Oh I forgot about that, he could probably benefit from reading angular guides on [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-appunless-property)

Comment: @Keff I NO HANVE ANY ERROR

Comment: Okey, maybe try what stavm said `*Permission="User:Main"`

Comment: @Keff not work .

Comment: What "AccessName" reffers ??
try change from : @Input() AccessName: string;
to : @Input('Permission') AccessName: string;

you can also implement OnInit and put your "this.show();" in ngOnInit method.

Comment: @Alexandre still not worked

Comment: If you want to put "User:Main" string, please change in your html to : [Permission]="'User:Main'" or Permission='User:Main'

[] syntax mean you want to bind var from your component

Comment: Can you tell us what's your angular version ? :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is with passing value to the directive attribute `Directive="User:Main"`.

In the [guide](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-appunless-property) by Angular they do it as follows:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appPermission]'
})
export class Pemsittiondirective {
    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private permission: PermissionValidate
    ) {
    }

    @Input() set appPermission(accessName: string) {
        if (this.permission.validateAccessLevel(accessName)) {
            this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainerRef.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

> The directive consumer expects to bind a true/false condition to [appUnless]. That means the directive needs an appUnless property, decorated with @Input
>   **Angular Says in the Guide**

And as @Stavm already mentioned - it's a structural directive. So you will need to use the `*`.

Then you can use it:

```
<li *appPermission='"User:Main"' class="side-menu-items-item"></li>
```

Here is an example I've made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjewlg

This example is working.

Comment: damn! Give me a moment, I'll test it locally.

Comment: It is working for me, at least in this simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjewlg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Is it not working or is it not behaving as you expected? Can you verify if `get appPermission` is being called?

Comment: it was not enterd to directive

Comment: Are you importing shared module properly? The component where you use the directive must have access to the Directive, can you try importing it in the same module as the component where this is done `<li [Permission]='User:Main'>` -- I doubt it's this, as it would throw error if it does not find it...

Comment: @Kianoush, see that Keff has changed the selector of the directive **appPermission** (you has **Permision**)

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark as valid solution!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot you're dealing with **structural directives**, hence, you need a template to work with.

to simply things, the Angular team created a syntactic sugar in the form of a star prefix:

```
<li *Permission="true">
```

made a small demo for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyfpty?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

First, as @Stavm already mentioned - its structural directive. Second you have you pass a string, but you are passing params. You pass a string as follows (double brackets):

```
*Permission="'User:Main'"
```